# is it possible to deactivate conditional compilation symbols at runtime?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm pretty sure the answer is **NO** but I just want to make sure it is impossible to **DEACTIVATE** code between conditional compilation symbols at **runtime**, ex;

```
/* code that make this been skip*/

#if DEBUG
    /* some code here */
#endif
```

without doing something like this;

```
public class test
{
    public static bool ActivateDebug = true;

    public void SomeMethod()
    { 
        /*some code*/

        #if DEBUG
        if (test.ActivateDebug)
        { 
            /*some code */
        }
        #endif

        /*some code */
    }
}
```

Comment: `if` statement is used for runtime, `#IF` - for compile time. And there is no reason to exist something else

Comment: No, _compilation_ being the operating word in `conditional compilation symbols`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, conditional compilation symbols are controlled during the pre-processing of the compilation. This means that the code between `#if` and `#endif` is actually removed (or adding whether the flag is true or false) by the compiler.

Since the code is not even there in the compiled application, there is no way to "magically" get it back.